# Excel to Json Conversion In Java

Tags: java, json

I have a problem where I would like to convert the below Excel data into a JSON format containing children. Here is the information about what I am talking about.

[Given excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghi9R.jpg)

This data needs to be converted to the below format but unfortunately, I am unable to do so!

[Type of JSON data needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkC6D.jpg)

Here is the updated code snippet I am using to get the data.

```
public static void excel2Csv(String file_path) {

    // Variables!
    Books b1, b2 = null;
    String jsonInString = "";
    int active_sheet_index = 0;

    // Initializing the parent and the children list!
    List<Books> bList = new ArrayList<Books>();
    List<Books> children = null;

    // Initializing the excel variables!        
    Sheet sheet = null;     
    Workbook workbook = null;
    FileInputStream inp = null;

    // Initializing the JSON Mapper variables!
    ObjectMapper mapper = null;

    try {
        // Reading the excel input for conversion!
        inp = new FileInputStream(new File(file_path));

        // Creating the excel workbook object!
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);     

        // Get the first sheet!
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(active_sheet_index);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            b1 = new Books();
            children = new ArrayList<Books>();

            // Iterating through the excel rows!
            Row row = iterator.next();

            // If Cell0 of the active row is blank or null!
            if(row.getCell(0)==null || row.getCell(0).getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                b2 = new Books();               
                b2.setBauthor(getCellValueAsString(row.getCell(1)));
                b2.setBcost(getCellValueAsString(row.getCell(2)));
                children.add(b2);
            } else {
                b1.setBname(getCellValueAsString(row.getCell(0)));
                b1.setBauthor(getCellValueAsString(row.getCell(1)));
                b1.setBcost(getCellValueAsString(row.getCell(2)));              
            }

            if (children!=null && children.size()>0) {
                b1.setChildren(children);
            }
            bList.add(b1);
        }

        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(bList);
        System.out.println("Final Json= \n" + jsonInString);

        // Convert object to JSON string and save into file directly
        mapper.writeValue(new File("D:\\test.json"), new JSONTokener(jsonInString).nextValue().toString());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Pojo Class**

```
public class Books {

    public String bname, bauthor, bcost;

    public List<Books> children;

    .... // Getters & setters 
}
```

Please take a look and suggest your view or a sample code snippet to generate the data in the specified JSON format.

Comment: Excel uses comma separated values (or `.CSV`). You have to convert from `.CSV` to `JSON`

Comment: @RyanSchaefer - Okay I will convert the excel to ".csv" format (comma separated) but how can I achieve the supplied format in which I need to retrieve the JSON data (i.e. a particular record have multiple children). You can take a look at the "Type of JSON data needed" image! Much appreciate your help!

Comment: Looking at your "Type of JSON data needed", you might need to add a children field in the `Books` class. Based on the image, children is a list of type `Books`. Once you populate `bList`, my best guess is `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString` will do it's magic.

Comment: @jpllosa - Thanks for your comments! Can you share a code snippet?

Comment: Show your `Books` class code with the children field. We'll go from there.

Comment: @jpllosa - Here is the code for the ``books``.  

`package com.jcg.csv2excel;  

public class Books {

 public String bname, bauthor, bcost;

 public List<Books> children;
`

Comment: With that Books class. Try populating data to your bList. Hardcode it just to see how it works. Then pass bList to ObjecMapper.writeValueAsString. The output should look like the type of json data you need.

Comment: @jpllosa - I did. But the result is not what I am expecting! shall I share the new main class code?

Comment: Sharing it would be a good idea. Don't try to read the Excel file just yet. Hardcode the values first to your bList. That way you can see if you are on the right track. Show the JSON output as well.

Comment: @jpllosa - Shared! Please check!

Comment: Where? Post it with your question. You can edit your own question.

Comment: @jpllosa - updated the implementation method and added the variables for the pojo class.

Comment: Please show what the output looked like with hardcoded values.

Comment: @jpllosa - I was able to figure out the logic using the dynamic values and it's working fine now! Thanks for your help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Book {
    private final String name;
    private final String author;
    private final String cost;

    private final List<Book> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Book(String name, String author, String cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public void addToChildren(Book book) {
        children.add(book);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public List<Book> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((author == null) ? 0 : author.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((children == null) ? 0 : children.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((cost == null) ? 0 : cost.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Book other = (Book) obj;
        if (author == null) {
            if (other.author != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!author.equals(other.author))
            return false;
        if (children == null) {
            if (other.children != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!children.equals(other.children))
            return false;
        if (cost == null) {
            if (other.cost != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!cost.equals(other.cost))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [name=" + name + ", author=" + author + ", cost=" + cost + ", children=" + children + "]";
    }


}
```

Runner code that uses `Book`.

```
    @Test
    public void batra() throws Exception {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

        // this where you're logic in populating the books list goes.
        Book book1 = new Book("Software Craftmanship", "Pete McBreen", "26");
        Book book2 = new Book("Chad Fowler", "The Passionate Programmer", "16");
        Book book3 = new Book("Core Java", "O'Reilly", "11");

        Book book2Child1 = new Book("Software Craftmanship", "", "26");
        Book book2Child2 = new Book("Agile Development", "", "32");
        Book book2Child3 = new Book("Continuous Delivery", "", "41");

        book2.addToChildren(book2Child1);
        book2.addToChildren(book2Child2);
        book2.addToChildren(book2Child3);

        books.add(book1);
        books.add(book2);
        books.add(book3);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        System.out.print(mapper.writeValueAsString(books));
    }
```

Output:

```
[ {
  "name" : "Software Craftmanship",
  "author" : "Pete McBreen",
  "cost" : "26",
  "children" : [ ]
}, {
  "name" : "Chad Fowler",
  "author" : "The Passionate Programmer",
  "cost" : "16",
  "children" : [ {
    "name" : "Software Craftmanship",
    "author" : "",
    "cost" : "26",
    "children" : [ ]
  }, {
    "name" : "Agile Development",
    "author" : "",
    "cost" : "32",
    "children" : [ ]
  }, {
    "name" : "Continuous Delivery",
    "author" : "",
    "cost" : "41",
    "children" : [ ]
  } ]
}, {
  "name" : "Core Java",
  "author" : "O'Reilly",
  "cost" : "11",
  "children" : [ ]
} ]
```

As you can see, the output is similar to your **Type of JSON data needed**.

Comment: Thanks, Joel! But I am looking for a dynamic snippet to putting the type of JSON data to a list and later passing this list to the JSON mapper. You can refer my code I have put up in the question! :D

Comment: You'll have to figure out the logic to that. Take a look at the runner code. Basically, you read the excel file then create a `Book` object, check if it is a child if it is add it to the parent book then add the book to the list... that is your pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. I was able to figure out the complete logic and is working fine now!

Comment: Brilliant! Way to go! :)